# My IIS7 get 500 error after I installed .NET Framework 1.1

Tags: iis-7

When I connect to any website it now says:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I have uninstalled .NET Framework 1.1 now but it's still the same (even an index.html cannot be shown).

Any idea ? It's urgent thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be related to metabase compatibility:
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get the websites working again:

Open the command prompt and go to `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` and

`run aspnet_regiis.exe -r`

Answer (score -2):

It is due to broken aspnet_filter.dll path. Look here: https://forums.iis.net/post/2027552.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.